# Bean Order value is Mysteriously null

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

I'm trying to get two filters, one to catch jwt's and another to catch API keys. Here is my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    
    @Autowired
    private ApiKeyRequestFilter apiKeyRequestFilter;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }


    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    SecurityFilterChain jwtFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            return http
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/authenticate",
                            "/register",
                            "/refresh",
                            "/post_appointment",
                            "/delete_appointment",
                            "/get_times",
                            "/get_services",
                            "/sendResetPassword",
                            "/sendSupport",
                            "/paymentWebhook",
                            "/api**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).build();
       }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    SecurityFilterChain APIFilterChainConfig(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            return http
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(apiKeyRequestFilter, JwtRequestFilter.class).build();
    }
}
```

Running this gives me this error:

`Error creating bean with name 'APIFilterChainConfig' defined in class path resource [com/reporter/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'APIFilterChainConfig' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.FilterOrderRegistration.getOrder(java.lang.Class)" is null`

This is confusing since I am clearly setting the order. Is it an issue with the filter itself? It's not very clear so any help would be appreciated. I'll also add this is part of a larger effort to modernize my security config according to this page: https://www.danvega.dev/blog/2023/04/20/multiple-spring-security-configs/.

Comment: what version of spring security are you using ?

Comment: You're definitely onto something. I set the version to 5.1.5.RELEASE and now I get the message: "Description:

Parameter 0 of method jwtFilterChain in com.reporter.config.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration." Trying to work through it now.

Comment: any particular reason to why you are not using the built in JWT features provided by spring security to verify JWTs? Also please note that handing out JWTs to browsers is very insecure, and jwts should not be used as session tokens in end clients like browsers, as they lack important security features that cookies have, using jwts as session holders makes you application suceptible to token steling attacks, csrf attacks, some cases DDos attacks etc.

Comment: I'm reading you. I'll close the quesiton and rethink how I'm doing things for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not about the order of the `SecurityFilterChain` but the order of the filters within a particular `SecurityFilterChain`. The problem comes from the following line in `APIFilterChainConfig`

```java
.addFilterBefore(apiKeyRequestFilter, JwtRequestFilter.class)
```

The filter class that are specified in `addFilterBefore()` should be a spring security built-in filter which its ordering are explicitly defined in [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/d23b231ac3137190c2af4b2fafe5ed3fe72a4a87/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/FilterOrderRegistration.java#L72) or a filter that is successfully defined to be added to the same `SecurityFilterChain` before such that spring security has enough information to know what filter chain position should it add `apiKeyRequestFilter` to.

`JwtRequestFilter` apparently is not the spring security built-in filter and so spring security does not know its order value to make such decision and hence throw this exception.

To fix the problem , you have to add `apiKeyRequestFilter` to the `SecurityFilterChain` based on one of the built-in filter which its know its order value, maybe just before `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` if that makes sense :

```java
.addFilterBefore(apiKeyRequestFilter,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
```